# RxApp initialization errors in nunit tests

Tags: .net, nunit, reactiveui

I'm trying to run NUnit tests that use ReactiveUI objects.

For a new test I'm consistently getting the following exception

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.RxApp' threw an exception.
 ----> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'ReactiveUI.IActivationForViewFetcher' from assembly 'ReactiveUI, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Other tests in the same assembly that use ReactiveUI work. I have no idea why this error is occurring

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue and it went away after upgrading to ReactiveUI 6.

Comment: Fortunately our project is upgrading to RxUI 6 shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this test work on its own? Are you overriding the service locator in a different test and possibly not resetting it?